# Textsize in subfloat figure

Tags: subfloats, fontsize, size

Is there any way of controlling the size of the subcaptions in a subfloat?

I've used:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{fig:Pic_a} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{Picture1}} \quad
\subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{fig:Pic_b} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{Picture2}}
\end{figure}
```

So I've like to make the Subcaption1 and Subcaption2 smaller in textsize.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can define caption fonts size and shapes with options when loading `subfig` or with `\captionsetup[subfloat]{KV-list}`. for details see package documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As given in table 3 of the `subfig` manual, use e.g.

```
\usepackage[
 font=footnotesize
 ]{subfig}
```

Alternatively, `scriptsize` or `small`. You can also set the font of the number and caption separately, with `labelfont=...` and/or `textfont=...`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[
 font=footnotesize % or small or scriptsize
 ]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{fig:Pic_a} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{Picture1}} \quad
\subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{fig:Pic_b} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{Picture2}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the example code was not included, so here is one example code snippet.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=scriptsize,textfont=scriptsize}
    \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{fig:Pic_a} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{figures/fig1}} \quad
    \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{fig:Pic_b} \includegraphics[width = 2.9cm]{figures/fig2}}
\end{figure}
```